# Can't access a partition I've created

Tags: permissions, ownership

I've spent 4 hrs going through all the relative forum q&a's and I still cant fix my problem. I am very much a newbie
I've created a partition `/dev/sda2/` at `/mnt/sda2/`. Its an `ext4` partition and I've given it the label 'Disk2' .
I cant access or share it because its owned by root.
Can someone who is patient pls help?

Comment: How do you mount the partition?

Answer (score 0):

As you have it mounted:

```
echo $USER
cd /mnt/sda2
sudo chown USR:USR .
```

... where you must replace the two `USR`-instances with what `echo $USER` prints. **(Untested!)**

Comment: Sorry for the harsh words, but that's all quite nonsense.

Comment: Then please take a constructive leap and add something fpr me and others to learn from. I'll remove the nonsense as you have done so.

Comment: While same thing as above you can use $USER. `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/sda2`  Often better not to use device name as mount, just to avoid confusion. I might then mount as /mnt/Disk2 if that is the name you like. But make sure you have not already mounted with Naultilus as it can only be mounted once.  I also like to give myself permissions to use it. `sudo chmod -R a+rwX,o-w /mnt/sda2` but note that -R is recursion and all lower level folders are also changed. Never run on a system partition as you will just then have to reinstall and restore from backups.

Comment: @oldfred as this was a just partitioned, formatted and mounted disk, `chmod 755 -R .` (or whatever) should not be necessary in my opinion, but I might be wrong. I was in doubt about when $USER:$USER gets evaluated, therefore avoided it.